# Semantic HTML Practice: the navigation list

Tags: html, image, navigation, html-lists, semantic-markup

I just realised that hiding text is a bad attempt from a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669736/semantic-html-practice/4669861#4669861) I just made,

> As a sidenote, Google does not like
>   hidden text, and if you have a lot of
>   it, it will consider it deceptive
>   coding. One is probably fine, but
>   you'd be better off using the alt
>   attribute on the image tag.

But I sometimes need to use images for navigation link list such as the one below, so I use css image background on `<a>` tags and hide the actual text in the html using `<span>`,

```
<div id="header" class="align-center">
 <ul id="menu-header">
    <li id="menu-header-home"><a href="#" class="current-header"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-header-portfolio"><a href="#"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-header-profile"><a href="#"><span>Profile</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-header-newsletter"><a href="#"><span>Newsletter</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-header-blog"><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-header-shop"><a href="#"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
</ul>        
</div>
```

is it seriously lack of semantic and 'it will consider it deceptive coding.' as I have used many many hiding text due to replacing text with images?

what should I do instead if I have to use an image for a button and images for navigation link list?

thanks.

Comment: css text-indent can be used to move text off the screen. Will that work?

Comment: I never knew about the use of text-indent. I am going to give it a go. thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the text also means it'll be missed by some screen readers.

A better way to do this would be either to use text-indent to position the text way off screen, use absolute positioning on the spans to also position them way off-screen, or simply make them visibility: hidden.

Comment: thanks. can I ask - is 'display:none' the same as 'visibility: hidden'? aren't they both are for hiding text??

Comment: They are. I think I've read somewhere that more screen readers will read out visibility:hidden than display:none, but I'm not sure now - looking for some definite info.

Comment: @lauthiamkok - `display: none;` completely hides the element and the browser will treat it as it's not there while `visibility: hidden;` hides the element for viewers, but the browser will treat it as it is still there. Example: A div containing a `visibility: hidden;` element will be the same size as the hidden element (unless otherwise told by CSS) while a div containing a `display: none;` element will be 0px x 0px (unless otherwise told by CSS)